# Issue refunding a cancelled order using Shopify REST API

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template, shopify-activemerchant, shopify-javascript-buy-sdk

I am trying to cancel and refund an order using this endpoint:

https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/orders/order#cancel

With the following payload:

```
{"refund": {
    "shipping": {"full_refund": true},
    "refund_line_items": [{
        "quantity": 1,
        "line_item_id": 2032498606169,
        "price": "39.90",
        "subtotal": "39.90",
        "total_tax": "6.37",
        "discounted_total_price": "39.90",
        "total_cart_discount_amount": "0.00",
        "location_id": null,
        "restock_type": "no_restock",
        "discounted_price": "39.90"
    }],
    "transactions": [{
        "amount": "39.90",
        "maximum_refundable": "39.90",
        "kind": "refund",
        "parent_id": 1147873263705,
        "currency": "EUR",
        "order_id": 922997620825,
        "gateway": "amazon_payments"
    }],
    "notify": true
}}
```

The order has just this one article, so I am basically refunding the entirety of this order.

However, this REST API call returns success, but when I go check the order's page, I do see indeed that the order was cancelled, but there was no refund after all.

[image]

And the order status displays "Canceled", "Paid", "Unfulfilled". So I end up having to refund it manually.

Why is my REST call just cancelling this order, but not proceeding with the refunding?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong reference. From your reference the cancel post should be:

```
POST /admin/api/2019-04/orders/#{order_id}/cancel.json {} // post an empty object -- not null
```

The Refund api at https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/orders/refund#create shows a slightly different POST body than what you supplied. You don't need any of the price info in your refund_line_item.

Have you verified the parent_id in the refund is a `sale` or `capture` transaction and that the gateway type matches.

Comment: Thank you for sanity checking what I was doing. My error was founded in their example called "Cancel and refund an order using the refund property", in the link I posted above on their documentation. But for reason it doesn't work. But if I use the refund endpoint like you suggested, it works.

Comment: Also, all that info (transactions and refund_line_items) was generated by shopify using their calculate endpoint (https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/orders/refund#calculate), so I assume it is 100% correct.